# Heaviest subgraph algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have the following problem at hand: there is a weighted undirected graph from which i want to extract the heaviest subgraph. I have two restrictions:

1. subgraph should have `N` nodes
2. subgraph should include a specific node `X`

I have some mathematical background, but by no means i am an expert on graph theory. Being said, it appears to me that the most straight forward way to deal with this problem is to perform some kind of a breadth-first search starting at `X` and calculating all the possible subgraphs with the length `N`, and then pick the heaviest one. And i think, even without implementing such solution i can see that it might take ages for somewhat complex graphs. So, here am I. And the questions are:

1. Can someone suggest a better algorithm for such task? Perhaps there is a known one which can be tweeked  to serve my needs? I cant seem to find any.
2. Does adding extra required nodes (e.g sying that "subgraph should include a specific nodes `X`, `Y`, `Z`") reduces the complexity? If so, then how? I'm pretty sure it does, but i cant figure out a decent way to use extra nodes in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (apart from the two restrictions) includes the max-clique problem.
The second restriction does not reduce complexity.
If it would, then you could run it for each node separately and still end up with a good algorithm for the max-clique problem.
The first restriction does not help either, since $N$ is not specified: it could be larger than the largest clique in the system.

So, give up all hope to find an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Well, i do not exactly need a clique, just any subgraph. But, i guess, it only complicates things. Bad news for me then. Luckily, even though `X`, `N` and weights are all variables - the graph structure is fixed, so i will probably be able to come up with some kind of optimisation. Thx for your reply.

Comment: I did understand that you do not need a clique.
But if you take an arbitrary graph, give all edges weight 1 and all edges of the complement weight 0
and take $N$ to be the size of the largest clique, then your algorithm, executed on the resulting complete graph
finds maximal cliques. Your general problem is harder even.